# 停止中のコンテナ起動エラー_container_linux.go:380:

Tags: python3, ubuntu, docker, jupyter-lab

#### 実現したいこと

Seleniumを利用したChromeの自動操作をしたいため、コンテナ内にChromeLinux版＋そのverに対応するChromeドライバーを導入したい。
その為に、Dockerfileを追記更新、Imageから再Buildしコンテナ再作成したい。

##### 実行環境

Windows 11
WSL2 / Docker Desktop for Windows
Ubuntu_latest ベースイメージからカスタムしたコンテナ内にPython-Anaconda開発環境を作ってコーディング中

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

以下dockerfileとdockerコマンド実行し、image作成できた。docker imagesでimage確認できた。また、停止状態のコンテナの存在まで確認できた。

その後、`docker-compose up -d` や `docker start` や `docker run` など起動を色々試したが、停止中のコンテナから起動ができないエラー

##### 更新して実行したDockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /tmp

ENV TZ=Asia/Tokyo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo wget vim curl gawk make gcc git portaudio19-dev unzip

RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    bash Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh -b  && \
    rm -f Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo bash -  && \
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV PATH $PATH:/root/anaconda3/bin

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pandas_datareader
RUN pip install mplfinance
RUN pip install japanize-matplotlib
RUN pip install selenium
RUN pip install webdriver_manager
RUN pip install tweepy
RUN pip install spotipy
RUN pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
RUN pip install pydub
RUN pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio
RUN pip install Scrapy

RUN wget --quiet http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz -O ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
    cd ta-lib/ && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
    make && \
    sudo make install && \
    cd .. && \
    pip install TA-Lib && \
    rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add && \
    wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_103.0.5060.134-1_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get install -y -f ./google-chrome-stable_103.0.5060.134-1_amd64.deb
    

ADD https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.134/chromedriver_linux64.zip /opt/chrome/
RUN cd /opt/chrome/ && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip

ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/chrome

RUN mkdir /workspace

CMD ["jupyter-lab", "--notebook-dir=/workspace","--ip=0.0.0.0","--port=8888" ,"--no-browser", "--allow-root", "--LabApp.token=''"]
WORKDIR /
```

##### 実行したDockerコマンド

- `docker build . --no-cache`
- `docker ps -a`
- `docker-compose up -d` や `docker start` や `docker run` など

##### 実行時のエラー

```
ERROR: for docker-python  Cannot start service jupyterlab: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "jupyter-lab": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for jupyterlab  Cannot start service jupyterlab: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "jupyter-lab": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

#### 試したこと

Jupyter Labの実行ファイルがないとのメッセージで、今回追記した部分を削除し元のdockerfileに戻してimageから再Buildすると普通にコンテナ作成されJupyter Labも起動し使える。
Jupyter Labの実行ファイル自体が存在しない訳ではなく、PATHが変わっておかしくなっているのでは？と想像。

元のdockerfileに対して追記した差分は以下のみ

```
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add && \
    wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_103.0.5060.134-1_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get install -y -f ./google-chrome-stable_103.0.5060.134-1_amd64.deb
    

ADD https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.134/chromedriver_linux64.zip /opt/chrome/
RUN cd /opt/chrome/ && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip

ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/chrome
```

#### これまで調査した事

以下サイトなどでエラーコードから原因調査しているが、どうしても対処策が掴めない状況

https://teratail.com/questions/8txy5vcbxqd0ee

Comment: 発生している問題の解決には直接関係ありませんが、同じような環境構築の記事としてはこの辺が参考になるかもしれません。[WSL2 に Anaconda経由で JupyterLab環境を構築する手順](https://kondeneenen.com/wsl2_anaconda_jupyterlab/), [WSL2 に Anaconda をインストールして JupyterLab を使う](https://qiita.com/honda28/items/a07dd84c51986e096139), [\[python\] Dockerでjupyter labの仮想環境構築．](https://akitoshiblogsite.com/docker-python-jupyter-lab/)

Comment: アドバイス戴きありがとうございます。戴きましたサイト参考にさせて戴きます。